What is the weights argument in glm.fit?
I just literally don't understand what the weights argument is in glm.fit. Could you give me a really simple example so that I know how to interpret it and know how it works?
If you think it's really beyond my ken, just recommend me other articles or videos that you believe might be helpful.
I tried reading some articles (for instances, the below ones) but I still don't get it
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2023/12/conquering-unequal-variance-with-weighted-least-squares-in-r-a-practical-guide/
Estimating Distributions of Weighted Data
How to find the weight of the weighted least squares regression analysis?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghs69kGWwAA
Thank you very much!
